# Prove using induction $\prod_{i=1}^n (1-2^{-i}) ≥ \frac{1}{4} + 2^{-(n+1)}$ for all n∈N

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Prove using induction
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-2^{-i}) ≥ \frac{1}{4} + 2^{-(n+1)}$$ for all n∈N

My answer so far:

base case: n = 1.  P(1) = $$(1-2^{-1}) = \frac{1}{2} ≥ \frac{1}{4} + 2^{-(1+1)} $$ so it holds.

induction hypothesis: Assume P(k): $$\prod_{i=1}^k (1-2^{-i}) ≥ \frac{1}{4} + 2^{-(k+1)}$$

induction step:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k+1} (1-2^{-i}) = (1-2^{-(k+1)})\cdot\prod_{i=1}^k (1-2^{-i}) $$

$$ ≥ (1-2^{-(k+1)})\cdot(\frac{1}{4} + 2^{-(k+1)})$$

I don't know where to go from here. I tried expanding to pull out the right inequality but can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple errors in $(1-2^{-1}) = \frac{1}{4} ≥ \frac{1}{4} + 2^{1+1} = \frac{1}{4}$ ...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
(1-2^{-(k+1)})(2^{-2}+2^{-(k+1)}) &= 2^{-2}+2^{-(k+1)}-2^{-2}2^{-(k+1)}-2^{-2(k+1)}\\
&= 2^{-2}+2^{-(k+1)}(1-2^{-2}-2^{-(k+1)})\\
&\geq  2^{-2}+2^{-(k+1)}(1-2^{-2}-2^{-2})\\
&= 2^{-2}+2^{-(k+2)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

you just need to develop the product and the results comes by itself.

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k+1} (1-2^{-i}) = (1-2^{-(k+1)})\cdot\prod_{i=1}^k (1-2^{-i}) $$

$$ ≥ (1-2^{-(k+1)})\cdot(\frac{1}{4} + 2^{-(k+1)})$$

$$ ≥ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}(1-(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}))  $$

and because $$ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}: \; \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \leq \frac{1}{2}  $$

you have the answer

Comment: This is a fairly minor point, but you switched from using $k$ to $n$ between the second & third lines of your equation.

Comment: oh! good point! bad habit of copy pasting from the question. thank you, i'll update